# Loop through each cell in a table and get its respective title

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Below is the example of my table.I know its bad ..some website provided data like this.I need to convert to some better format.

[image]

So I want to loop through all cells and get its respective title.

for example output should be like..

```
01001 - Dairy and Egg Products
01002 - Dairy and Egg Products
.
.
.
.
02001 - Spices and Herbs
02002 - Spices and Herbs
```

My code so Far in php , I am sorry I searched in stackoverflow and google I am unbale to find answer and I have no Idea how to do it.Some help is appreciated.

```
$qrelated= inputs("SELECT * FROM `table`");

while($row = $qrelated->fetch_assoc())
{

}
```

Comment: `foreach($row as $key => $value){ echo $value." - ".$key; }` ?

Comment: Thanks ! I am such a Fool..now I get it..Can u answer it so I will accept or shall i delete this dumb question...awkward

Comment: It's up to you. I've posted by comment as an answer if you wish to accept it. You could always edit your question to make it slightly more generic and leave this question here to be used as a canonical answer for linking to other future similar questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to print out each column heading and it's value for each row using something like this:

```
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    echo $value." - ".$key;
}
```